# Can my custom tabbar be created like so for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, tabbarcontroller

I have designed a custom tabbar and the developer says the design I created can't be done.

The screen is made up of a usual background with a tabbar.  I'd like my tabbar to look a little different to the usual iPhone style.  I would like at the bottom of the tabbar a grass illustration (transparent) and on top would sit all the separate buttons and on top of those would be the icons.  All of these images (as seen in link below) are separate .png files.

When the user scrolls the content, it will scroll under the transparent grass.  The buttons of course will be clickable and have a different view for an active state.

Please see the link below to see a mock-up of the image:

http://www.stuartkidd.com/dummy.jpg

I'd appreciate if the community could explain to me if this could be done and if so, how.  I thought it would have something to do with 'creating a custom tabbar'.

And a further question, if it can be done, can also the tab buttons be horizontally 
scrollable with a swipe action?

Thanks,

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, i would like the text put on to the buttons via programming and don't want to create the text graphically.

Answer (score 2):

It all **can** be done but you are going against the Iphone UI guidelines. You won't be able to leverage the UITabbarView to do what you want so you'll basically have to write the whole thing from scratch. Your tab bar would be a scroll view with a row of buttons representing each tab. When a button is clicked you load in the appropriate view. The UITabBar controller gives you a lot of functionality for free and I suspect once you start working towards this you'll see exactly how much extra work this will end up costing you. Going against the way Apple does things can be a slippery slope.

Another idea might be to keep a hidden UITabBar to manage the tabs and call it from your custom tab bar. This would free you from a lot of the hassle of swapping views/controllers in and out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row of custom buttons and have 2 subviews. One for the bottom navigation bar and one for the content view where you will be swapping your content based on what is pressed.
You can have a state which maintains what was clicked. Based on that you can set the button enabled state for every button in your bottom bar.

```
button.selected = YES
```

It will be easy to handle the touch up inside events and properly load appropriate views in and out of the bigger subview as they will be part of the same view controller.
I have implemented a similar functionality and it works well but still in process of submitting it to the app-store.